# Why do my items with javascript go in front of my Nav

Tags: html, css

My nav keeps going behind any items I have that contain javascript.
I've tried changing the z-index of both items but I'm not sure how else to fix it

http://flavorsbyj.site/#Reviews

View this site and scroll down... This also happens if you scroll up a bit with the pictures slideshow. Both which contain Javascript

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 5000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow-container col-6 col-m-12" style="background-color:#E7E7E7; border-radius: 1vh;">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img alt="Event2" src="Images/E2.1.jpg" style=" border-radius: 1vh;" class="col-20 col-m-0">
    <img alt="Event2" src="Images/E2.1.jpg" style=" border-radius: 1vh;" class="col-0 col-m-20">
  </div>



  <div class="row" id="navbar" style="position: fixed; width: 100%;">
    <div class="col-m-4 col-4 dropdown-right">
      <span id="bar" style="font-size:9vh;cursor:pointer; color: #232323; margin-left: 10px; padding: 10px; text-shadow: 1px 2px white" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 col-m-4">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-m-4"><img alt="Logo" src="Images/Logo.jpg" class="col-9 col-m-20" style="height: 13vh;"></div>
    <div class="col-2 col-m-0">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-m-0 col-5">
      <a href="Home.html" style=" text-align: right; margin-top: -1vh;">
        <img alt="RampCert" src="Images/Ramp.png" class="col-20 col-m-20" style="height: 10vh;">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-m-7 col-0">
      <a href="#Home" style="text-align: right; margin-top: -1vh;">
        <img alt="RampCert" src="Images/Ramp.png" class="col-20 col-m-20" style="height: 10vh;">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hey LexLex. Please include all necessary code to reproduce your issue *in the question itself* as opposed to only an external resource. As StackOverflow strives to create a useful repository of answers for future readers, external resources that can go down, be deleted, etc, run the risk of making this question useless to future readers.

Comment: Side note, but I went to the link provided and don't see any issues.

Comment: is there any way I can add a picture to show my issue?

Comment: Hi LexLex, welcome to SO! Yes, you can add images to your question. I just tested your site using Safari's developers tools. I saw the problem with your `#navbar` and, as mentioned in other answers, adding a `z-index: 1;` (yes, 1 is enough) will indeed solve your issue. However, be mindful of your `height` attribute, as it is giving your navigation bar (and other elements) a weird behavior under screen size testing.

Comment: In addition to the above, you might also encounter another problem when adding the z-index, and that's the `.sidenav`. You should also increase the `.sidenav`'s z-index accordingly (2). Side note, you have 2 resources not found (404); and `openNav()` and `closeNav()` functions in JS find a null reference, throwing errors.

Comment: I fixed the side nav and the close button seems to work for me. What else throws errors?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a `z-index` to your `#navbar` then it will be front of your content.

Example:

```
#navbar {
  z-index: 999 //or any value bigger than 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the z-index value. Just replace your #navbar inline-css with following css and it will work as expected

```css
#navbar {
z-index:9999; /*Change this value accordingly */
}
```

OR

```html
<div class="row" id="navbar" style="position: fixed;width: 100%; z-index: 9999; ">
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @LexLex Sorry. Just update the inline css. I have updated the answer. If it solves the issue, do accept the answer . :P

Answer (score 0):

Solution is `z-index` for sure as there is already answer by couple of other people.

I would say while using the `z-index` you must have to make sure which element you want on the top on based on that only you can provide the `z-index` not just the random number to bring up like 999. `z-index` work like layers.

In your problem z-index:2 will resolve the issue too.

```
#navbar {
    z-index: 2;
}
```